# set title toolbar in android fragment giving null pointer

Tags: android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

i want to set toolbar title in android fragment. but my code giving null pointer exception in below code:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PROFIL");
```

this is my full code

```
package id.prasetyo.appsgaul.Layout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import id.prasetyo.appsgaul.R;

public class Profil2Activity extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener  {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profil2, container, false);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

       ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar

     ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle( "PROFIL");


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
    }
}
```

any suggestion would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace ?

Comment: I meant stack trace..log cat ?

Comment: What is a current theme applied on Activity

Comment: null pointer at the line which i mention

Comment: i use theme noactionbar

Answer (score 2):

Move the below code from `onCreateView()` method to `onActivityCreated()` method.

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PROFIL");
```

Only after the `onActivityCreated()` you can be sure that there is an `Activity` returned from `getActivity()`.

And use `getView()` instead of `rootView` inside `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: A single line ```((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.the_title)
``` has worked for me, even if I'm not using a toolbar, but an ActionBar. The thing is I still get a NullPointerException warning.